# Displaying an item

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am creating my first apex application and I have a bunch of items which have been populated. I wanted to display them all on the page just to verify that the right values are being stored.

I have created a new region named params and within that region I want to display the items. For example I have the item :P1000_USERID all I want to do is display that value on the page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have various options, including:

1. You could set the item type to something other than Hidden and ensure that it doesn't have a condition to prevent it being rendered.
2. You could display the item values in the region body with text like:
       P1000_USERID = &P1000_USERID.
   For example this region definition:
   [image: Region definition]

   shows:

[image: Region rendered]

Comment: so I created a new HTML region and when I put that in it just outputs P1000_USERID = &P1000_USERID. it doesn't replace &P1000_USERID with the actual value.

Comment: Well it should - it does for me.  I'll post what I did in my answer.